# Fuse.js returns no search results

Tags: javascript, fuse.js

Using Fuse.js `v3.0.5` and chrome `59.03071.115` I get no search results with simple Fuse.js call.

```
let fuse = new Fuse([{hmm: "no result"}], {keys:["hmm"]})
fuse.search("no")
```

Result is an empty array.  I have tried both the CDN and latest NPM package.

The same code works as expected in Safari.  Haven't tested Firefox yet.

Comment: Hey you got the solution to this problem?

Comment: No, I ended up switching libraries.  I can't remember to which one.

Comment: Which library have you used?

Answer (score 0):

I found [fuzzy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuzzy) to behave more like what you would expect form fuzzy search than Fuse.js.